# Collecting multiple values from different rows and creating columns from them in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, inner-join

I want to import data from one sql database to another. The database containing the data is structured differently than the one I have now.

My database has the tables Person and Person_Data

Person columns:

```
id(PK, int) | Person_Name(text)| Person_Data_id(FK, int)
```

Person_Data columns:

```
Person_Data_id(PK, int) | Date_Of_Birth(text)| City_Of_Birth(text) | Favorite_City(text)|
```

The other database has the neccesary data to populate this, but is structured a bit differently. It has these tables:
ExternalPerson, ExternalProperty

ExternalPerson columns:

```
|PersonID(PK, int)  | Name(string)  |

|   0               |"John"         |
|   1               |"Bob"          |
```

ExternalProperty columns:

```
|PersonId|PropertyName|PropertyAttribute|PropertyValue|

|   0    |"Birth"     | "City"          |"Rome"       |
|   1    |"Birth"     | "City"          |"Vienna"     |
|   0    |"Birth"     | "Date"          |"1982-02-01" |
|   0    |"Favorite"  | "City"          |"New York"   |
```

As you can see, the external database contains information that could be inserted in the regular one. It's just that some of the columns are stored in rows instead. I want to merge it, so that, for each PersonID, we pick up the Value for Birth and City and put it in City_Of_Birth etc. The external database is structured so that each combination of PersonID, PropertName and PropertyAttribute only has one row, so there is no risk for disambiguity. All combinations of PropertyName and PropertyAttribute present in the external database also have a correcponding column in the Person_Data table. There might be missing data though, for example in our case, Bob does not have a value for date of Birth or Favorite city, in which case those entries should be null. That is, I want to transform the two tables ExternalPerson  and ExternalProperty into

```
|id(PK, int)|Name  |Date_Of_Birth|City_Of_Birth|Favorite_City|

|auto       |"John"|"1982-02-01" |"Rome"       |"New York"   |
|increment  |"Bob" |    NULL     |"Vienna"     |NULL         |
```

I have tried various combinations of JOIN, GROUP BY, SELECT CASE WHEN and COALESCE to no avail. I feel like this should be possible to do, but have not succeded to find the SQL commands to extract the rows from the external database into columns. For example the line

```
SELECT 
    Name, 
    PropertValue AS City_Of_Birth
FROM 
    ExternalProperty

WHERE PropertyName LIKE 'Birth' AND PropertyAttribute LIKE 'City'
```

will output the City_Of_Birth in a single column together with Name, but I don't know how to aggregate the result.
Does anybody have any idea on how to do this? Thanks in advance.

I am using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2017 and Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM) - 14.0.1000.169 (X64)

Comment: SQL Server Management Studio 2017 (AKA SSMS 2017) isn't an RDBMS, it's an application for interaction with SQL Server. It'll (probably) be worth updating your post to include the version of SQL Server you have (`PRINT @@VERSION;`). Saying you have SSMS 2017 for your RDBMS is like saying *"I am using Office 2016."* when asked for what version of Windows you have.

Comment: Included the question now with the SQL Server version number

Answer (score 1):

You can aggregate with MAX()

```
MAX(CASE WHEN PropertyName LIKE 'Birth' AND PropertyAttribute LIKE 'City' THEN PropertyValue ELSE NULL END) AS City_Of_Birth
```

Comment: Is that line missing a closing parenthesis somewhere? Where should it be positioned in that case?

Comment: Yes it was.  I added the missing paren.